# Move repository files under different folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've created some time ago a repository with many files in it but without any structure like folder 'root' and folder 'tags' and so on. Now I would like to create folder 'root' and put my current work in there, and than create  a branch called tagv23 in folder 'tags'. I've created in TortoiseSVN in repo-browser folders root and tags. How to move my all other folders and files to folder 'root' that it will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the files using drag and drop, when browsing the repository.

Comment: It's too simple to be obvious

Comment: +1 if you mean browsing folders in Repo-browser.. 'cause this works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially going to branch your existing files and folders. It's always a copy operation, so copy your existing files and folders to the 'root' folder and then delete the originals. Now you can branch from 'root' to 'tagv23'.